# How do I change a specific TD's background color on click with JavaScript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a `<td style="background-color:white"></td>`.

I want to make it so that when I click inside that `td`, the background-color changes to black. How do I accomplish this with jQuery? Is it onmousedown event or click event?

With normal JavaScript I tried:

```
<td style="background-color:white" onclick="$(this).onmousedown('background-color','black')">SomeText</td>
```

...but it didn't work...

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "normal" javascript but your example uses jquery.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try this...

#### jQuery

```
$('td').click(function() {
   $(this).css('backgroundColor', '#000');
});
```

...or....

```
$('table').on('click', 'td', function() {
   $(this).css('backgroundColor', '#000');
});
```

#### JavaScript

```
[].forEach.call(document.getElementsByTagName('td'), function(item) { 
   item.addEventListener('click', function() {
       item.style.backgroundColor = '#000';
   }, false); 
});
```

...or...

```
var table = document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0];

var changeStyle = function(e) {
    if (e.target.tagName == 'td') {
        e.target.style.backgroundColor = '#000';
    }
};

table.addEventListener('click', changeStyle, false);
```

The latter examples only binds one event handler.

It may be better to add a class, so you can specify your styles in a stylesheet and not couple your presentation and behavioural layer.

#### jQuery

```
$('td').click(function() {
   $(this).addClass('active');
 );
```

...or....

```
$('table').on('click', 'td', function() {
   $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

#### CSS

```
td.active {
  background: #000;
}
```

The reason this didn't work...

```
<td style="background-color:white"
     onclick="$(this).onmousedown('background-color','black')">
     SomeText
</td>
```

...is because there is no `onmousedown()` event on the jQuery object (though there is [`mousedown()`](http://api.jquery.com/mousedown/)).

Comment: Is there a way to do this within the TD tag itself?

Comment: @Teivere Yes, you could add the `onclick` attribute, but it is better to use obtrusive event handlers, e.g. attach them from your JavaScript.

Comment: @Teivere - it's a best practice to keep your javascript separate from your HTML

Comment: I tried putting this in the head tags, but didnt work, but it did work when I put it in the body tags after the table is written in html. is that a requirement or is there a way to have it work putting the code in the head tags?

Comment: That comment should be *un*-obtrusive event handlers :)

Answer (score 3):

The correct function is [mousedown](http://api.jquery.com/mousedown/). But you can just use a [click](http://api.jquery.com/click/).

```
<table> ... </table>

<script>
    $("table tr td").click(function() {
        $(this).css("background", "#fff");
    });
</script>
```

**[See this example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k8UgT/)**

---

It is recommended that your script is not mixed with HTML, but this is valid:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td onclick="$(this).css('background', '#fff')">change color</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**[See this example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k8UgT/1/)**

Your onclick event was *trying* (incorrect syntax) to bind an event on itself and it wasn't changing the element style.

---

**[This example shows why the same script on the head doesn't work.](http://jsfiddle.net/k8UgT/3/)**

`.bind` or `.click` will bind to existing elements, `live` will bind on any element, even if it is inserted afterwards.

jQuery references

- [click](http://api.jquery.com/click/)
- [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/)
- [$(fn)](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Comment: I tried putting this in the head tags, but didnt work, but it did work when I put it in the body tags after the table is written in html. is that a requirement or is there a way to have it work putting the code in the head tags?

Comment: If you want to put in the head tag use `live` instead. What happens is that your script element on the head executes before the body is rendered. You can either use `live` which will bind the event even if the element doesn't exist yet or use `$(function(){})` to execute a function when the page is loaded. I will update the answer to be more clear.

Answer (score 3):

I think jquery may be overkill here. You can just use something like this.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td onclick="javascript:this.style.background = '#000000';">this</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

You can play with it here - http://jsfiddle.net/yVvyg/

This can also bedone from the head tag

```
loadtheclicks() {
var ar = document.querySelectorAll("td"); //could also use getElementByTagname
        for (var i=0; i< ar.length; i++) {
            ar[i].addEventListener("click", function() { this.style.background = '#000000'; }, false);
        }
}
```

Just call that onload and you should be gold. I have that on jsfiddle as well - http://jsfiddle.net/2anSz/4/